# Basic use of getByXpath in HtmlUnit

Tags: java, web, htmlunit

This has been my best attempt at it:

```
HtmlUnorderedList unorderedList = (HtmlUnorderedList) page.getFirstByXPath("//ul[@id='inbox-message-list-messages']");
```

However, that getFirstByXpath returns `null`. Just learned about using xpath today so I'm sure I'm missing something basic.

[image: code]

Answer (score 1):

Once we have a reference to an `HtmlPage` we can search for a specific `HtmlElement` using one of `get` methods or `XPath`. Check the following example of finding a `div` by an ID, and getting an anchor by name:

```
@Test
public void getElements() throws Exception {
    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://some_url");
        final HtmlDivision div = page.getHtmlElementById("some_div_id");
        final HtmlAnchor anchor = page.getAnchorByName("anchor_name");
    }
}
```

And `XPath` is the suggested way for more complex searches ([tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp)) :

```
@Test
public void xpath() throws Exception {
    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net");

        //get list of all divs
        final List<?> divs = page.getByXPath("//div");

        //get div which has a 'name' attribute of 'John'
        final HtmlDivision div = (HtmlDivision) page.getByXPath("//div[@name='John']").get(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add that, you compare real Chrome result with HtmlUnit, which may differ.

First you need to ensure you construct with Chrome simulation:

```
try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {
}
```

Then you should see what HtmlUnit sees, by printing:

```
System.out.println(page.asXml());
```

Then see the elements, and use the `XPath` accordingly, as hinted by `akhil`.